# Can’t add pagination in camunda embedded form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, camunda, camunda-modeler

I have table (in my embedded form) and i want to add pagination , here i have added div with pagination functions :

```
 <div data-pagination="" data-num-pages="numOfPages()" 
      data-current-page="curPage" data-max-size="maxSize"  
      data-boundary-links="true"></div>
```

and i have relative code in javscript

```
//pagination
    $scope.curPage = 1,
     $scope.itemsPerPage = 3,
     $scope.maxSize = 5;
     items = answer;
  $scope.numOfPages = function () {
    return Math.ceil(answer.length / $scope.itemsPerPage);

  };

    $scope.$watch('curPage + numPerPage', function() {
    var begin = (($scope.curPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage);
    var end = begin + $scope.itemsPerPage;
    console.log(begin);
    console.log(end);
    console.log( answer.slice(begin, end));
    $scope.filteredItems = answer.slice(begin, end);
  });
```

i should have received response like this:
[image]
but instead i can’t see pagination at all (p.s i can’t see any errors in console)
what should i change to make pagination work properly?